# Descobrir o tipo de variável em ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um formulário em rails de busca que pode receber um CEP ou o nome de uma rua, com isso preciso saber qual o tipo da variável o usuário está entrando, caso seja números, faço uma pesquisa por CEP, caso seja texto, faço uma pesquisa pelo nome da rua

Comment: Para esse específico caso, *Expressão Regular* é o que você precisa usar.

Comment: Acho que você quis dizer o "tipo de conteúdo" que existe dentro de uma variável string. Confere ? Altera a questão pra ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

É possível utilizando [Regular Expression](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), faz a verificação conforme os tipos de caracteres ou padrão de caracteres.

Ex:

```
[0-9] - Apenas numeros
[a-zA-Z] - Alfabeto com letras minusculas e maiusculas
```

> Pesquise sobre variações caso precisar montar padrões especificos, é muito útil em determinados
>   cenários.

https://guru-sp.github.io/tutorial_ruby/expressoes-regulares.html

http://diegorubin.com/2011/04/16/utilizando-expressoes-regulares-em-ruby

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

Para descobrir o tipo da variável utilize o método `kind_of?`, pois ele devolve um valor booleano.

use dessa maneira:

```
variável.kind_of? tipo
```

Exemplo para descobrir se "x" é do tipo inteiro:

```
x.kind_of?Integer
```

Comment: Pode formatar o que é código do que não é na resposta? Assim fica mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez fazendo uma comparação usando o `.class`
Acho que o `.class` pode te ajudar dando a informação da variável necessária, daí é só fazer a comparação!

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):006:0> Integer = 1
(irb):6: warning: already initialized constant Integer

=> 1

irb(main):007:0> 1.class

=> Fixnum
```

Esse seria uma maneira de descobrir o tipo da variável.